# How to display menu options in android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I am having trouble displaying my menu options on my phone. I got all the code right I think but it is not displaying. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how my manifest looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.drumloopsequencer"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Here is the onCreateOptionsMenu function:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
return true;
}
```

and here is the menu xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item 
    android:id="@+id/file"
    android:title="@string/fileTab"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

  <item 
    android:id="@+id/packs"
    android:title="@string/packsTab"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     /> 

  <item 
    android:id="@+id/drumRack"
    android:title="@string/drumRackTab"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

  </menu>
```

Comment: do u facing problem in fragment or any activity class??

Comment: thank you for the reply! and no, I am not receiving any errors, it just does not show my menu at all.

Comment: @JoseOrtiz put your .java file code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
super.onAttachedToWindow()
openOptionsMenu(); 
};
```

Comment: This made some sort of menu show up but sorta just in a corner of my app, it is intended to go on the actually actionbar and always be there. Any other suggestions? thank you very much by the way

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a fragment make sure that you have enabled the options menu with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. A good place to call this might be from `onCreate`.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
}
```

or for an Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am really new to android programming, so I am not even sure what a fragment is. So I am assuming that I am not using a fragment. any other ideas? thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Are you using an Activity then? If so you can use the same `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` call in the `onCreate` method on your Activity.

Comment: Yes I am using an Activity, I tried putting that line in the onCreate method but it gives me an error saying "the method setHasOptionsMenu(true); is undefined for the type Main

Comment: ahh yes, I missed the super call, but it has no effect in the results. I still get no menu

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment then you have to do this:

```
//inside constructor
 public MyClassFrag(){
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

or inside `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```